# Master ip has changed in postgresql replication

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have postgresql replication system with two machines, suppose I want to change the master ip,the streaming to slave machine will stop. Can I resume streaming with the new master ip instead of doing the replication from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just change `host` in `primary_conninfo` and restart the standby.

This replication parameter can be found in `recovery.conf` before v12 and in `postgresql.conf` after that.

Comment: Thank you @LaurenzAlbe, But the problem that I using  postgresql 11 and I didnt find `primary_conninfo` in postgres.conf. But finally I figure it out that its exist in `recovery.conf`.

In any case, thank you